# Import ckdtree in pycharm

Tags: python, import, scipy, pycharm

I have a project in pycharm and a virtual environment with scipy set up. I'd like to use the cpython implementation of the kdtree to speed up my kmeans algorithm. However, when I want to import the ckdtree in pycharm like this

```
from scipy.spatial import ckdtree
```

I get an 'cannot find reference' error. This error only occurs within pycharm as I'm able to 
import it in the terminal when I activate my venv there.

```
>>> from scipy.spatial import ckdtree
>>> ckdtree
<module 'scipy.spatial.ckdtree' from '/home/.../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/spatial/ckdtree.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'>
```

The corresponding file in the spatial folder is:

```
ckdtree.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

Any idea how I could tell pycharm that it exists?

Comment: check the python interpreter, which iinterpreteer it is taking

Comment: @temmo It is the virutal enviroment. All other scipy modules can be imported, including kdtree which is the pure python implementation and is in the same folder as ckdtree.

Comment: in pycharm  add python interpreter of your virtual environment.

Comment: @temmo As I sad, I already use the virtual environment as my interpreter in pycharm.